# How do I reference a variable/expression inside an expression in twig templating?

Tags: templating, variable

This is the desired code

```
<img src="{{ asset.getUrl('newsImageHalfWidth') }}">
```

Which works. However I want the transform name to be replaced by the contents of

```
entry.newsImageSize
```

So in a kind of pseudocode it would be

```
<img src="{{ asset.getUrl('{{entry.newsImageSize}}') }}">
```

which of course does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Twig, you'll never need to nest tags within other tags. In fact, it's impossible to do.

You can simply pass your variable into `getUrl` **instead** of using a string.

```
<img src="{{ asset.getUrl(entry.newsImageSize) }}">
```

Comment: Thanks. I've tried that and I get a 'Division by zero' error. But when I just use {{ entry.newsImageSize }} I get the transform name displaying on the page. So can't work out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I'm getting closer. I think the reason the code is not working for me is because entry.newsImageSize is from a dropdown field, and is therefore not a string. I'm now looking for a way to convert the variable to a string.

Comment: If you've got [`devMode`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#devMode) enabled, try using [`{{ dump() }}`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/dump.html) to figure out exactly what that value holds. You may also want to setup a conditional, to ensure that `entry.newsImageSize` is not empty before trying to use it.

Comment: Thanks for your help Lindsay D. The variable was not empty, but the wrong type, so when I converted to a string using `<img src="{{ asset.getUrl( "" ~ entry.newsImageSize) }}">` it all worked OK. There might be a more elegant way to do the conversion.

Comment: Check out the [the dropdown fields docs...](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/dropdown-fields) That may help you find a more elegant solution.

Comment: @LindseyD . is correct, you need to add ".value" to the end of your field reference. So: you need to do this first, to set a variable:
`{% set transformType =  entry.newsImageSize.value %}` Then you can do this for the image: `<img src="{{ asset.getUrl(transformType) }}">`